# SQL Pivot for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the below table 'EmpTemp':

```
Name | Category | Value1 | Value 2
John | Cat1     |  11    |   33
John | Cat2     |  22    |   44
```

I would like to have the below output for the table:

```
Name | Cat1_Value1 | Cat2_Value1 | Cat1_Value2 | Cat2_Value2
John |      11     |      11     |      33     |     44
```

I guess this give a basic idea of what kind of transformation i'm expecting. I have tried the below query that gives me a partial solution:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    Cat1 AS 'Cat1_Value1', 
    Cat2 AS 'Cat2_Value1', 
FROM EmpTemp AS T
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value1)
    FOR Category IN (Cat1, Cat2)
) AS PVT
```

The above query gives me the following result:

```
Name | Cat1_Value1 | Cat2_Value1
John |      11     |      11
```

I am stuck how can I extend this pivot query. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using `Pivot`.

First you need to `unpivot` the data then do the `pivot`

```
;with cte as
(
select name,val,col_name from yourtable 
cross apply (values 
            (value1,Category+'value1'),
            (value2,Category+'value2')
            ) cs(val,col_name)
  )
  select * from cte
  pivot(max(val) for col_name in([Cat1value1],
                                 [Cat1value2],
                                 [Cat2value1],
                                 [Cat2value2]
                                )) p
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of doing it without using the `pivot` syntax:

```
select name,
       max(case when category = 'Cat1' then value1 end) as cat1_value1,
       max(case when category = 'Cat2' then value1 end) as cat2_value1,
       max(case when category = 'Cat1' then value2 end) as cat1_value2,
       max(case when category = 'Cat2' then value2 end) as cat2_value2
  from EmpTemp
 group by name
```